# there is no date to in the record which it is needed to filter the data in the query

Tags: sql, firebird, firebird2.5

I have one question about sql, maybe someone can help me. In this case I have one table where records looks like this:

```
    Name       Account       Percent    MonthValue   DateFrom
    Element1   500             15       500         2016-01-01
    Element1   501             45       500         2016-01-01
    Element1   502             40       500         2016-01-01
    Element1   500             100      500         2017-01-01
    Element2   503             80       3000        2016-01-01
    Element2   504             20       3000        2016-01-01
    Element2   505             45       3000        2017-06-01
    Element2   503             55       3000        2017-06-01
```

I have to show result where in each other month I can see what Element have percent of account. For exemple Element1 in February 2016 on account 501 have 45 percent from value 1000 in fact 450. I have problem to show value when the same element have a few dates. For example in December 2016 Element1 have 3 accounts, but in January 2017 Element1 have 1 accounts. I have date from I should count, but I haven`t date to I should count. Result that I expect is like this:

I want to know what account and what percent of this accounts are in December 2016, I get result:

```
  Name      Account     Percent     Value
  Element1    500         15         75
  Element1    501         45         225
  Element1    502         40         200
  Element2    503         80         2400
  Element2    504         20         600
```

In other case I want to know what account and what percent of this accounts are in June 2017, and then I get result:

```
  Name      Account     Percent     Value
  Element1    500         100        500
  Element2    505         45         1350
  Element2    503         55         1650
```

I hope that I explain the point of problem. Below I show my sql in current form:

```
SELECT
a.NAME, 
a.ACCOUNT,
a.PERCENT,
a.MONTHVALUE,
a.DATEFROM
from ELEMENTS a
where a.DATEFROM between :DATE_FROM and :DATE_TO
```

where :DATE_FROM, :DATE_TO are parameters for comparison of dates (but I haven't column for comparison :DATE_TO). Please help me with that problem, I hope that someone know solution other than insert to table column which have date to.

Comment: So basically, a row is valid until newer row(s) with the same Element, but with a more recent date, replaces it? Also, why do you state that Element1 - account 501 has 45% of 1000? Shouldn't it be 45% of 500?

Comment: Yes, of course, my mistake:)

Comment: Do the examples with "I get result" show the **expected** result or the actual result?

Answer (score 0):

The following query outputs the desired result based on your examples:

```
declare @querydate date;
set @querydate = '2016-02-01'; --Set the desired query date

SELECT a.Name, a.Account, a.[Percent],
a.MonthValue * a.[Percent] / 100 as Value,
a.DateFrom
FROM ELEMENTS a
JOIN

(SELECT Name, MAX(DateFrom) as LastElementDate
FROM ELEMENTS
WHERE DateFrom <= @querydate
GROUP BY Name) b

ON a.Name = b.Name
AND a.DateFrom = b.LastElementDate
```

So the idea here is to create a subquery (table b) that contains the last recorded date for each Element. (MAX(DateFrom). Also, the @querydate is used to filter out unwanted rows where the date is higher than your desired date.
That table is then joined to the main table based on the Name and the LastElementDate, thus extracting only the records whose date matches the last valid date.

Comment: This question is about Firebird, you seem to be using Microsoft SQL Server syntax.

Comment: You're right, my bad, I didn't notice the Firebird tag. There might be a way to adapt it, but I can't test it for now

Comment: Besides the use of `declare` and `set`, and the `@` parameter marker and the use of square brackets instead of double quotes I think it will work (maybe the `100` needs to be replaced with `100.0` to ensure a double precision value).